# Why do not breakpoints work in vb6 project?

Tags: vb6, breakpoints

I have a problem in vb 6. I have a project with db Access. On the plan the same project need to do with db Sqlite. DB Access is converted to Sqlite. I installed ODBC drivers for Sqlite. I did changes in the project. The new project began to work in principe, but at course of work arised the following connected errors:

1. In the control ComboBox the event Click does not work. There is a connection between ComboBox and Click ie when I do double click on ComboBox procedure ComboBox.Click is showed. In run mode of app items of ComboBox are selected but code inside ComboBox.Click does not work. I decided to set a breakpoint inside ComboBox.Click. Here second strange behaviour of app arised.
2. At run of app run does not break at the breakpoint. I set breakpoints in other places of app but they do not work neither.
   Why do not the code inside ComboBox.Click and the breakpoints work?

I renamed the project and changed its location. No result.

Comment: Are you sure the control's name is correct in the click event? Does it match the signature in the dropdown for the event handler at the top of the editor?